# $f\in \mathbb{H}(\mathbb{C}\setminus A)$ show that $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A=\{\ z \in \mathbb{C }: \text{Re}z-5\text{Im}z \in \mathbb{Z} \}$
and  a continuous $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that  is holomorphic to $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ and $\underset{z\to\infty}{\lim}f^2(z)=10$,
show that $f$ is constant.

---

Basically, I have a continuous function which is bounded, the only ways (that I know of) to show $f$ is constant is to show that is  holomorphic to $A$ and use Liouville or  $f(\mathbb{C})$ is not connected. But I can't show neither, any hints ?

Comment: Use Morera's Theroem to show that $f$ extends to an entire function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how do you show that $A$ is open and connected ? Or countable ?

Comment: It is not connected. Draw a picture  and you will see why the union of the lines $x-5y=n, n \in \mathbb Z$ is closed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but still  I don't see why the integral over a closed path is zero.